# How can I check if executable JAR has started/finished running?

Tags: java, cron, executable-jar

I have multiple executable JARs, let's call them `task1.jar`, `task2.jar`, `task3.jar`, etc...
They mainly access the database and do housekeeping tasks on the server.

They are run by cron jobs, one after another, early in the morning everyday. The crob jobs are set about 15 minutes apart.

The crob jobs simply just call:

```
java -jar taskX.jar
```

Depending on the data on the database, their durations to finish will vary.

The task executions must not overlap. Otherwise when they access the database at the same time, the server will crash. It has happened before when one task takes too long to run and hasn't finished before another task has started.

So my question is... is there anyway to check a JAR has started or finished so that the next JAR can be delayed?

I would preferably resolve this with Java methods over changing any configs on server which I have limited access on.

---

Edit: @mksmanjit Sorry, I didn't mention before. There is also one complication - not all of them are run everyday. For example, `task1.jar` and `task3.jar` may be run everyday, `task2.jar` may be run every two days and `task4.jar` may be run every Mon, Wed, Fri, etc... So the situation can get quite complicated.

Comment: You can create a table in the DB(Assuming DB is common for all three task) which will keep track of this Application running like when it start it will add an entry to IN_PROGRESS and on complete mark it complete.

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of ways as I see it !**

1. Let all JAR (or tasks) write `Logs` in a `common` or a `separate` log file. (Usually feasible if you only want to capture minor details such as start time , stop time, result etc) Assuming format you keep is manually readable.
2. As per above suggestion, create a `Table` in `DB` to keep a track of task activity along with task name, it's details such as trigger by, start time, end time, result etc
3. Alternatively, create database `Triggers` to monitor event (such as write or read) on DB table and whenever your task executes, trigger will also execute depending on what DB actions you want your trigger to perform such as sending `e-mail`, writing to table, printing simple log
4. Let JARs (or tasks) also print logs on console just in case assuming they are designed to view from any console or UI at runtime !